# An internal error occurred during: "TestNG Result Listening Job". Port value out of range: -1

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

After installation of the update for eclipse on 1/2/2017 I got an error even for previously working tests:

> An internal error occurred during: "TestNG Result Listening Job". Port
>   value out of range: -1

I googled how to fix that - made an update for JRE to the last version 1.8.0_112 and uninstalled TestNG-Maven integration plugin but still got an error. Could somebody help me to fix the problem?

Console:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1  at
>   java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.InetSocketAddress.(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.BaseMessageSender.connect(BaseMessageSender.java:60)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.connect(MessageHub.java:31)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:105)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

Error log:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Port value out of range: -1   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.BaseMessageSender.initReceiver(BaseMessageSender.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.eclipse.ui.TestRunnerViewPart$3.run(TestRunnerViewPart.java:444)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Thank you!

Comment: Follow the potential issue there: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/306

Comment: do you see any stack trace on the "Error Log" view?

Comment: @XuQingTan, here are my console and error log messages at updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restored my Windows 10 an got no error any more.. It looks like there were no problems with Java, Eclipse or my code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why on your local that failed to get a free port:

```
public static int findFreePort() {
// Nick: either here throws IOException
    try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0)) {
// Nick: or, here return -1
        return socket.getLocalPort();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
    }
    return -1;      
}
```

> made an update for JRE to the last version 1.8.0_122

do you mean JRE 1.8.0_112 (rather than 122)?
do you have any anti-virus could impact the code?

or could you put the above code into a simple one-class java app, print the return value of `findFreePort`, and debug if you can reproduce in this simple app?

Comment: Yes, this is 112 ver. I just uninstalled Avast, standard windows antivirus still working. I run your class and received -1.

Comment: Could you debug the method to see why jre returns -1

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Winsock problem, not a problem with testNG itself. You
can reset your Winsock installation to setup defaults by following the
instructions from this KB [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/811259/how-to-determine-and-to-recover-from-winsock2-corruption-in-windows-se).

Try below steps in short:

1. in command prompt run `netsh winsock reset`
2. restart computer